# ISO Norm as basis for a good style guide

Tags: style-guide, iso-9241

*A few years ago I was attenting a conference for frontend web developers about good UX/UI with focus on how buttons in online shops should behave.*

In my hand written notes I found the following:
DIN ISO 9241-11 (Usability: effective, efficient and satisfactory)

Now I sadly can not really find helpful information on google on how this ISO norm connects to good website UX/UI.
I did find this: http://www.uml.org.cn/jiaohu/pdf/s1022.pdf which talks about the basics of Usability.

**But this got me thinking, is there a international norm which I could use as base for a style guide?** Or did someone already do so?

I am not only interested in web design but also in windows applications. Ideally answers reference german or english sources.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's exactly what the intention of the ISO standards are for, although I am not sure why they are not more commonly referenced.

If you look at [ISO 9241-210:2010(en) Ergonomics of human-system interaction — Part 210: Human-centred design for interactive systems](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:9241:-210:ed-1:v1:en), there are so many different sections that can easily be applied or adopted for a design system or style guide.

In fact, here are some examples of how the information in the ISO standard has been [applied in the design process](https://www.uxbooth.com/articles/designing-usability-standards/) that you can reference, and how this is essentially very similar to the more popular double-diamond and design thinking processes.

[image]